# Does 'View all data' permission in salesforce give users access to private reports of another user?

Tags: reporting, permissions, administration, security, dashboard

Does 'View all data' permission in salesforce give users access to private reports of another user? Couldn't find any exact theory on this.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. Please read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) and perhaps take the [tour] before you [edit] your question to show what you have tried and where you are stuck. As it stands, with no explanation of your research, it seems to me this question could easily be answered yourself with a little experimentation.

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not. [Report and Dashboard Folders](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.analytics_sharing.htm&type=5) says:

> The reports or dashboards in a private folder are always invisible to everyone except the person who created the folder.

There are no direct exceptions to this rule. Of course, a user with sufficient permissions can login as a user, then access their private reports.